# Shape Recognition CNN: Softmax Output is always 1

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, softmax, shape-recognition

I am trying to classify geometric shapes with respect to certain properties (such as edgy forms vs. round forms).
The output of my network is **always** either [1, 0] or [0, 1], even when the prediction is **wrong**. Is there a way to get useful softmax outputs (e.g [0.6, 0.4] if the prediction is unsure)? Ideally, I would like to read off the "obviousness" of the shapes' properties by the values of the softmax outputs (e.g. [1, 0] -> "The shape is very round." vs. [0.6, 0.4] -> "The shape is kind of round.").

You can find the architecture of my model in the code down below.

I would be very happy if someone could help me with this issue since it is my very first machine learning project.

Best regards,
Valentin

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflowjs as tfjs

X = pickle.load(open("Round.pickle", "rb"))
Y = pickle.load(open("Round.pickle", "rb"))

X = np.array(X/255.0)
Y = np.array(Y)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

#model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
#model.add(Activation("relu"))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", 
              optimizer = optimizer,
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size = 8, epochs = 5, validation_split = 0.1)

model.save('Round.model')
```

Comment: You can try adding more `Conv2D` layers. To avoid extreme outputs, use regularization techniques like weight decay, dropout etc.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. Adding a second Conv2D layer leads decreases the accuracy to only 50% (about random). I have just added a dropout layer between the two dense layers. Unfortunately, I still seem to get only [1, 0] predictions. Should I add more than just one dropout layer?
Thank you very much!